# R: Connect to SFTP with RCurl

Tags: r, curl, sftp, rcurl, fips

I'm trying to connect to a SFTP server. It is an encrypted server that uses FIPS mode. I am *able* to connect and perform file transfer through WinSCP, FileZilla, and through bash sftp commands *with no problems*.

But, I cannot, access this same SFTP from R using **RCurl** (R version=3.3.2, RCurl version=1.95-4.10, windows 10). This is what my code looks like and the error message that is being produced:

```
RCurl::ftpUpload(what="path/to/my/local/file.ext",
                 to = "sftp://my.eftp.server:portNumber/path/to/my/file.ext",
                 userpwd = "user:password",
                 .opts=curlOptions(verbose=TRUE))
```

The error message is:

```
*   Trying ###.###.###.##...
* Connected to my.eftp.server (###.###.###.##) port ## (#0)
* Failure establishing ssh session
* Closing connection 0
  Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failure establishing ssh session
```

Any help would be wonderful. I've referenced the following with no luck:
[sftp with R - sftp not a protocol with RCurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411969/sftp-with-r-sftp-not-a-protocol-with-rcurl),
[Using RCurl with SFTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268281/using-rcurl-with-sftp)
and the RCurl documentation (and other links).

I've also tried:

```
RCurl::ftpUpload(what="path/to/my/local/file.ext",
                 to = "sftp://user:password@my.eftp.server:portNumber/path/to/my/file.ext",
                 .opts=curlOptions(verbose=TRUE))
```

Also, I've checked my `curlVersion()$protocols` and scp and sftp protocols are listed (with the others).

Comment: I am having the same problem. Settings work just fine in WinSCP. But I cannot connect with any of the methods/examples I have found on Windows. On Linux it works.

Comment: Anyone get this one solved?  It's haunting me too.

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet! But I can confirm that it also works great in Linux, like Jan mentioned.